# Incubated but not hatched egg

Tags: pokemon-go

I got the message "oh" and it showed my egg. Before I could do anything the server went down. When I got back on my egg was gone. Is there anything I can do to retrieve my incubated but not hatched egg?

Comment: Did you check your new Pokemon?  It probably hatched.

Comment: The first thing I do once I get back into Pokemon Go after the app or server crashes is check the Journal. Look at what was the last thing that happened.

Comment: Btw, it looks like your not alone on this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sd25q/missing_pokemon_after_egg_hatch/

Comment: @Sync egg hatching doesn't show in the journal.

Comment: @Rapitor Ah, I didn't notice that. A lot of people on Reddit keep saying to check your Journal if your egg was missing after server crash, so I kinda assumed it'd be there. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 10):

You <strike>*most likely*</strike> *could have* got your Pokemon.

Sort your Pokemon by "recent" and look for a blue glow that indicates a Pokemon is recently added.

[image]

[image]

In the event your egg **really** disappeared, the answer is it's lost. As indicated by Sync in the comments, lost eggs is a **[common problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sd25q/missing_pokemon_after_egg_hatch/)**.

Niantic has warned against using high value items during times of server instability.. but eggs we can't really control. Your best bet would be to contact support.

I would consider this a high priority issue and use the "Report High Priority Issue" button.

Comment: Yup. Same thing happened to me. I did this and discovered that I had a new Geodude!

Comment: Also, there's this website called http://IsPokemonGoDownOrNot.com, which shows the status of Pokemon Go servers over a time period, it even says if its safe to put down a lure. So if you really get paranoid about this happening again then, everytime before you go for a walk/jog you can check this site to see if its safe to hatch 'em all.